# Embeded Conditional expression

Tags: r

I have a vector and a constant which I use in the expression below:   a through i are the results of a function

```
Y<- c(0.2,0.09,0.3,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.2,0.1,1)
x<- 0.13
G<-if(tail(Y,1)==1)

{a <- g*h
b <- i*r
d <- o*p
e <- j*k
f <- s*y
g <- t*w
h <- v*l
i <- n*m

if(x < 0.1)  a else 0+
if(x < 0.11)  b else 0+
if(x < 0.12)  c else 0+
if(x < 0.13)  d else 0+
if(x < 0.14)  e else 0+
if(x < 0.15)  f else 0+
if(x < 0.16)  g else 0+
if(x < 0.17)  h else 0+
if(x < 0.18)  i else 0}  else 0 

G
[1] 30
```

I would like to obtain result G which is the output of the sum of the first 3 (a,b,c) within the last expression between {}. Have tried with ifelse and does not work as it selects only just one as in the example above.

a through i are the results of a function, example below (can not place the function and the vector as is too long) and can not be sequenced as per the factors above exposed.

```
{a <- summary(ResFit)$coef[55]*summary(ResFit)$coef[91]
b <- summary(ResFit)$coef[56]* summary(ResFit)$coef[93]
c <- summary(ResFit)$coef[57]*summary(ResFit)$coef[95]
d <- summary(ResFit)$coef[58]*summary(ResFit)$coef[97]
e <- summary(ResFit)$coef[50]*summary(ResFit)$coef[99]
f <- summary(ResFit)$coef[59]*summary(ResFit)$coef[101]
g <- summary(ResFit)$coef[60]*summary(ResFit)$coef[103]
h <- summary(ResFit)$coef[61]*summary(ResFit)$coef[105]
i <- summary(ResFit)$coef[62]*summary(ResFit)$coef[107]
```

Many thanks

Comment: Just some advice: do you really need a-i for this question or is maybe a-e enough? It'd be neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use `cut()` to find the right range for the `x` value, and then you can use that as an index in into a vector of return values for each interval.

```
x <- 0.13
vals <- c(apply(embed(1:10,2),1,prod),0) #these are a..i values
z <- cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, .1,seq(.11,.18, by=.01), Inf), right=F) #find the interval
vals[z]
```

With the edit...

```
smry<-summary(ResFit)$coef
vals<-smry[c(55,56,57,58,50,59,60,61,62)] * smry[seq(91,107, by=2)]
x <- 0.13
z <- cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, .1,seq(.11,.18, by=.01), Inf), right=F) #find the interval
vals[z]
```

Comment: I have edited the question as the example provided did not reflect that a...i are specific results from another function, my appologies for not incorporating this before

Comment: @Barnaby This solution doesn't care where the `vals` vector comes from. I just did this silly trick because i didn't want to re-type all those numbers (your example is unnecessarily complex). So if you just turn your a..i values into an array, this will still work. Unless that wasn't what you were asking about in the first place; in that case, your question is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact I made the mistake of placing numbers instead of letters or the code to extract a coefficient which is what is in the sequence of a through i. I do not think  I could apply vals to this situation. z I believe is valid

Comment: @Barnaby I updated my answer with a new set of `vals` based on your update.

Comment: Many thanks very effective coding and it has the right answer

Comment: I have another question, if x < 0.1 would be constant from a to i how would you go on doing z